# Flutter How iterating through map and print values

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this problem that i don't know how to resolve:
In my application there is a Map that retrieve data from firebase database and up to here everything is ok.
Now I want to iterate along map to print the keys and the values inside a container in a scrollable page.

I wrote this code, it works, but this solution makes the container scrollable not page :(

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFF8F8FF),
        appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
          iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.blueAccent),
        ),
 body: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            slider,
            carDescrContent
          ],
        ));
```

```
 final carDescrContent = new Expanded(
        child: new Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                  new BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      blurRadius: 5.0,
                      offset: new Offset(0.0, 6.0))
                ]),
            margin:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 25.0),
            child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: map.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  String key = map.keys.elementAt(index);

                  return new Container(
                      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                      child:
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[new Text("${key}"), new Text(map[key])],
                  ));
                })));
```

[image: Screenshot of the page]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `carDescrContent` value with [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html). It is like a box which makes it child scrollable.